# What is difference between using perform method and not using perform method on viewContext ? - CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

### Background

I'm beginner at CoreData. Until now, I used `perform` method everywhere whenever I need to use CoreData - like fetching, save, update, ..
Thereby I also used `completion closure block`to pass data that was resulted from fetching.
Of courese, I always used `viewContext`because my app that I made doesn't need too much data. As I thought, App is working well.

but, after I think about CoreData more, then I realize that **"if I am using `viewContext`, I don't have to use `perform` method, and I don't have to use `completion closure block`. ".**

because `viewContext`is main queue for CoreData.

### Question

My question is that **"If I use `viewContext` and I don't need to execute task in background queue, Can I not using `perform` method?"**

I'd appreciate it if you can answer to me.

### Code

under the code that I used until now.

```swift
    func fetchTags(_ completion: @escaping (([Tag]?) -> Void )) {
        context.perform {
            let request: NSFetchRequest<Tag> = Tag.fetchRequest()
            guard let list = try? self.context.fetch(request) else {
                return completion(nil)
            }
            completion(list)
        }
    }
```

under the code that is better as I think.

```swift
    func fetchTags() -> [Tag]? {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Tag> = Tag.fetchRequest()
        guard let list = try? self.context.fetch(request) else {
            return nil
        }
        return list
    }
```

Comment: `perform` will make sure to execute the "next" commands in the correct thread for the `NSManagedObjectContext`. Who can certify that `fetchTags()` will be called always in the correct thread for `viewContext`? There is no guarantee. Now, it's up to you to use the safe guard or not. What if tomorrow you decide to handle a background thread too? You will need to update all your current code. Also, if you use background request at some point (like a Web API call), you might need to certify the thread at some point... Etc To compare, I'd say it's like a helmet while riding a bike...

Comment: @Larme  Thank you so much. I haven't thought about using Networking. You're right! It opens my eyes to use perform!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `viewContext`, **and your code is running on the main queue**, then `perform` and `performBlock` are unnecessary. If you can always guarantee that the code runs on the main queue, you can simplify it. If there's ever a chance of running it on some other queue, you need to take precautions to avoid crashing.